# Databricks - FileNotFoundException

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm sorry if this is basic and I missed something simple.  I'm trying to run the code below to iterate through files in a folder and merge all files that start with a specific string, into a dataframe.   All files sit in a lake.

```
file_list=[]
path = "/dbfs/rawdata/2019/01/01/parent/"
files  = dbutils.fs.ls(path)
for file in files:
    if(file.name.startswith("CW")):
       file_list.append(file.name)
df = spark.read.load(path=file_list)

# check point
print("Shape: ", df.count(),"," , len(df.columns))
db.printSchema()
```

This looks fine to me, but apparently something is wrong here.  I'm getting an error on this line:
`files  = dbutils.fs.ls(path)`

Error message reads:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File/6199764716474501/dbfs/rawdata/2019/01/01/parent does not exist.
```

The path, the files, and everything else definitely exist.  I tried with and without the 'dbfs' part.  Could it be a permission issue?  Something else?  I Googled for a solution.  Still can't get traction with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a folder named "dbfs" if your parent folder starts from "rawdata" the path should be "/rawdata/2019/01/01/parent" or "rawdata/2019/01/01/parent".

The error is thrown in case of incorrect path.

Comment: I actually tried that before posting my question.  There must be SOMETHING else that I just can't see here.  There is an endpoint exposed, and a URL, but I don't think those belong here.  Thanks.

Comment: @asher , why don’t you set path as “/“ and see if you see the folder and add one folder at a time

Comment: Brilliant!  I just tried that and got this: 
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.;

Comment: Then, if I try this '/rawdata/' or this 'rawdata/', immediately I get the same error that I initially had.

Comment: @asher, if you are still having problem with listing files in a dbfs path, probably adding the response for dbutils.fs.ls("/") should help. If the file is of type Parquet, you should be having the schema in the file itself. if not specify the format and schema in the load command. note the load command assumes the file is Parquet if the format is not specified.

Comment: Thanks Abraham!  What would the code look like?  Could you update your first response?

Comment: @asher, added details to my original response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58205129/is-there-a-way-to-load-multiple-text-files-into-a-single-dataframe-using-databri/58207194#58207194 . try and see if works for you.

Comment: I made the change that you suggested, but that's at the end, right. I can't even get that far. The error occurs on line 3, which is: files  = dbutils.fs.ls(path)

Comment: I think this is close, thought. Based on all the documentation that I read, I'm sure this will work, I just to figure out what the damn problem is.

Comment: So, I just ran this: dbutils.fs.help()
That gives me this: dbfs:/mnt/rawdata/2019/01/01/parent/
So, there is a ':' character in there.  That was throwing things off.  Now, I'm getting this error: com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.common.InvalidMountException:

Comment: As I said earlier your parent folder is mnt and there is no dbfs folder :-). you can omit dbfs:/ from path "/mnt/rawdata/2019/01/01/parent/" and it should still work.

Comment: I tried that before and I just tried it again.  It does not work for me.  I'm getting the same error: 
com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.common.InvalidMountException
Thanks for trying to help!  I really appreciate it!  I'll consider different approaches.  This simply is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but if someone is still looking for a solution:
It does require path to be listed as:
"dbfs:/rawdata/2019/01/01/parent/"